# Fix GetFirmwareEnvironmentVariable function usage in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi, pinvoke

I'm trying to implement [GetFirmwareEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getfirmwareenvironmentvariablea) function. I think my implementation is wrong, because I always receive a string of unintelligible characters except for the `PlatformLang` and `PlatformLangCodes` variables. (you can see more variable names [here](https://uefi.org/specs/UEFI/2.10/03_Boot_Manager.html) to test them.)

For example, for the `ErrOut` variable I get a string similar to this: `?ÐA??????????€ÿ`, while for `PlatformLang` I get a readable "en-US". For other variables (like `SecureBoot` or `TimeOut`) I just get "[]" which I guess it represents a string of an empty array.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
Public Class NativeMethods

    <DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
    Public Shared Function GetFirmwareEnvironmentVariableA(varName As String,
                                                           vendorGuid As String,
                        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysUInt)> buffer As IntPtr,
                                                           bufferSize As UInteger) As UInteger
    End Function

End Class

Public Shared Function GetFirmwareEnvironmentVariable(variableName As String, vendorGuid As Guid) As String

    ' Privilege SE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_NAME required to obtain firmware environment variables.
    Const requiredPrivilege As ProcessPrivileges = ProcessPrivileges.SystemEnvironmentPrivilege
    Try
        ProcessUtil.SetCurrentProcessPrivileges(requiredPrivilege, PrivilegeStates.PrivilegeEnabled)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try

    Dim value As String = Nothing
    Dim buffer As IntPtr
    Const bufferSize As Integer = 4096

    Try
        buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize)
        Dim retSize As Integer = NativeMethods.GetFirmwareEnvironmentVariableA(variableName, $"{{{vendorGuid}}}", buffer, bufferSize)
        Dim win32err As Integer = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()

        Select Case win32err

            Case Win32ErrorCode.ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER ' 87
                Throw New Exception("Invalid parameter format.")

            Case Win32ErrorCode.ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND ' 203
                ' Variable not found, ignore (return an empty string).

            Case Win32ErrorCode.ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD ' 1314
                Throw New Exception("Privilege 'SE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_NAME' is required.")

            Case Win32ErrorCode.ERROR_SUCCESS ' 0
                value = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buffer, retSize).Trim(ControlChars.NullChar)

            Case Else
                Throw New Win32Exception(win32err)

        End Select

    Finally
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Buffer)

    End Try

    Return value

End Function
```

Example usage:

```
Dim variableName As String = "ErrOut"
' Dim vendorGuid As New Guid("8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c")
Dim value As String = GetFirmwareEnvironmentVariable(variableName, Guid.Empty)
```

Note that I tried to implement the Unicode version without success. Only the ANSI returns me readable text for some variables. For sure I'm doing something wrong with that P/Invoke definition.

Comment: Maybe good idea to confirm/infirm your result with powershell command `Get-UEFIVariable -VariableName ErrOut`. it doesnt work on my PC as I am in legacy boot mode (I suppose). look at this excellent work of Michael Niehaus here ; https://oofhours.com/2019/10/05/working-with-uefi-variables-from-powershell/ . you can also unzip it's nuget package to get source code exemple relative to GetFirmwareEnvironmentVariableA. (public licence).

Comment: AFAIK, there's nothing wrong with your code (I would definitely use Unicode instead of ANSI but that won't change the return type), it's just many return values are not of the string type. I use this type of code (C#) https://gist.github.com/smourier/d7dabccb2c0473eb08c295e30141f46f that can dump the return as hexa so you can check the bits.

Comment: @Simon Mourier Thanks for this nice example. Maybe a "thanks only" comments are not allowed, but this is also to say that I confirm the example solves my doubts, it is a solution to this question post.